# How to changes the Route::set in kohana 3.2

Tags: php, kohana-3, kohana-3.2, kohana-3.3

we have used kohana 3.2.
We need to changed the url xyz.com/ar measn the site working arabic lanugag and xyz.com/en means the site working in english language. 
Now the default 3 param is id. I need to changes this.

```
  Route::set('custom', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
        ->defaults(array(
            'controller' => 'admin',
            'action'     => 'index',
    ));
    Route::set('live', 'ar/auctions/live')
    ->defaults(array('controller' => 'auctions','action'  => 'closed','method' => NULL));
```

Answer (score 0):

1 [Route::set()](https://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Route#set) have 3 parametrs. Last is *Regex patterns for route keys*

2  The sequence is important, so first `live`, second `custom`

3 Try this:

```
Route::set('other', '((<lang>)(/)(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))))', 
                     Array('lang'=>'(en|ar)'))->defaults(array(
    'lang'       => $default_lang,
    'controller' => 'foo',
    'action'     => 'index',
));

I18n::lang(Request::instance()->param('lang'));
```